# How to get rid of DataMember from a Hierarchy

Tags: tfs, mdx

in my dimension hierarchy I'd like to remove the "system-generated" DataMember. The hierarchy tree is composed as follows:

- A

  - **A**
  - A.A

    - **A.A**
    - A.A.A
  - A.B

Where **A** and **A.A** are DataMember which corrupt the hierarchy.

I'd like to have the real hierarchy like this:

- A

  - A.A

    - A.A.A
  - A.B

What are the MDX techniques for filtering out the system-generated DataMember in a hierarchy dimension?

More specifically I'm working on TFS OLAP, Work Item Tree dimension.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A litte late for an answer, but since I couldn't find a quick solution, I came up with the following:

```
Filter(
    Descendants([Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level 02].Allmembers),
    NOT [Dimension].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent.DataMember IS [Dimension].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.DataMember
)
```

*Note: I'm using the level dynamically in my original MDX statement. Replace the descendants function as desired.

Answer (score -1):

```
FILTER (
    DESCENDANTS( [Work Item Tree].[Work Item Tree Hierarchy].[Work Item Tree].ALLMEMBERS ),
    NOT [Work Item Tree].[Work Item Tree Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.IS_DATAMEMBER
)
```